# What is the definition for a hyper-humid area?

Tags: climate, humidity, evapotranspiration

We can use the aridity index $\left ( ai = \dfrac{P}{PET} \right )$ to define arid areas. Hyperarid areas have $ai < 0.05$. Is there a similar threshold for hyper-humid regions?

Would it be 20 (inverse of the threshold for hyperarid)?

Comment: You might want to give a source for your aridity index and what the variables stand for, as it's not something used in broader meteorology/climatology too heavily I don't believe.

Comment: It certainly wouldn't be 20 as the aridity index defined that way (annual precipitation divided by potential evapotranspiration) is necessarily between 0 and 1.

Comment: @DavidHammen That doesn't sounds right, there are plenty of places where P > PET, e.g., cloudy tropics: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41597-022-01493-1/figures/2